# Selenium, automated frontend testing on different OS

Tags: unit-testing, cross-platform, selenium, automated-tests, cross-browser

My complete working environment is Linux based (Ubuntu for desktop and server). I use Hudson and Selenium to execute tests on my EE6/ZK web application with any browser available for Ubuntu.

But how would I test my application with IE (Windows) without setting up a Selenium server in Windows. Thought I could run Windows in a VMWare or Virtualbox, but still it needs a "local" selenium and how would I trigger it ? Install hudson as well and pretty much replicate the complete CI in Windows ? How is MAC ?

Any tips or experience with cross-browser-platform-OS automated testing ?

Sven

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use Selenium Grid. There is a Selenium plug-ins for Hudson available, and this [article](http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/continuous_testing_with_selenium_grid_subversion_and_hudson.html) has a guide how to setup Continuous Integration with Hudson and Selenium Grid. And yes, you will have to install Windows in a virtual machine.