# Is it possible to perform cross browser testing with selenium IDE recorded scripts?

Tags: selenium-ide

I would like to run selenium IDE recorded script to multiple browser so, could you please tell me how to perform ?
If it's not possible could you tell me what tools available with features like Record and play back and cross browser support for that script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium, automated frontend testing on different OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332811/selenium-automated-frontend-testing-on-different-os)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but in some cases you may have to make small adjustments depending on how you wrote your script, like change the id of a button, for example, in FF the id is 100, and on IE it's 115, but if you used the xpath text locator, to click on the button by it's name, you won't have this problem.

I posted a solution i used to execute my FF scripts on IE, you can do the same for Chrome with the Chromedriver:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467827/4321163

Note that this solutions are for the "old" IDE, the current "new" IDE is still crude and missing a lot of the features the old one has.